# Websocket communication versus Netty Environment

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I need to implement the communication between two Java environments. The recipient is a SpringBoot reactive application and the snippet to handle the communication is as follows (I'll skip the configuration of the beans)

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    return webSocketSession.send(webSocketSession.receive() // <- Step 0
        .map(message -> {
            log.info("Step 1");
            return message.getPayloadAsText();
        })
        .map(message -> {
            log.info("Step 2");
            return webSocketSession.textMessage(this.receiveMessage(message));
        }));
}
```

The client part is implemented using the Http API from java 11

```
WebSocket webSocket = HttpClient
    .newBuilder().executor(executor).build()
    .newWebSocketBuilder()
    .buildAsync(URI.create(url), new WebSocket.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
            log.info("onOpen using subprotocol " + webSocket.getSubprotocol());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
            log.info("onText received with data " + data);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onText(webSocket, data, last);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onClose(WebSocket webSocket, int statusCode, String reason) {
            log.info("Closed with status " + statusCode + ", reason: " + reason);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onClose(webSocket, statusCode, reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
            log.error("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onError(webSocket, error);
        }

    }).join();


webSocket.sendText(toJSON(List.of("Lorem", "Ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet")), true);
webSocket.sendClose(WebSocket.NORMAL_CLOSURE, "ok").thenRun(() -> log.info("Sent close"));
```

Using debug, I can notice that once the `join()` is completed and the `WebSocket` instance is returned, the method at Step 0 of receiver is executed and the `Mono<Void>` instance is returned.

But the problem is that even if I send some text, Steps 1 and 2 are never executed!

If I try the reverse communication (sending something from the SpringBoot application to the Sender app) the messages are received.

Finally, this is the log from the `onClose` callback execution after the `sendClose` statement.

```
Closed with status 1002, reason: Server internal error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Since `buildAsync` method return an instance of `CompletableFuture<WebSocket>`, we need the chain the send of the messages before flush the messages queue using `join()`

Here the solution

```
WebSocket webSocket = HttpClient
    .newBuilder().executor(executor).build()
    .newWebSocketBuilder()
    .buildAsync(URI.create(url), new WebSocket.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
            log.info("onOpen using subprotocol " + webSocket.getSubprotocol());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
            log.info("onText received with data " + data);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onText(webSocket, data, last);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onClose(WebSocket webSocket, int statusCode, String reason) {
            log.info("Closed with status " + statusCode + ", reason: " + reason);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onClose(webSocket, statusCode, reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
            log.error("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onError(webSocket, error);
        }

    })
    .thenCompose(ws -> ws.sendText(toJSON(List.of("Lorem", "Ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet")), false))
    .thenCompose(ws -> ws.sendText(toJSON(List.of("Lorem", "Ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet")), true))
    .thenCompose(ws -> webSocket.sendClose(WebSocket.NORMAL_CLOSURE, ""))
    .join();
```